# To Catch A Planet

Tags: science-based, planets, space

Let's suppose we live in different star system with two similar-sized planets (with a mass of three and a half Earths.) We live in Planet A, which is habitable. For some reason, Planet 2, our neighbor, enters in collision orbit with our Planet 1. But us, Planet-1ers are not happy with this, so we somehow *catch* Planet 2 and keep it close together. Both planets end up as a double planet.

Now, what would it take to catch Planet 2 and keep it orbiting along with ours? I'm aware that with current technology it is not possible, but let's suppose for a moment we have an advanced level of technology, but still not going off the laws of nature.
[image: Double Planet]

Comment: Answer: a lot of handwavium

Comment: Someone can probably calculate the required energy...which will have a lot of digits, but if you are asking about a *method* that would probably fall under *idea generation* and would be off topic.  Interesting idea though.  Welcome to the site.

Comment: What Rob Watts said. You may want to start at [Dealing with sense of scale in space](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/2667/29), then follow the links in that question as well as the comments to it. We get questions every now and then about doing things to planets, and the answers pretty much boil down to "it's hard. like, really, really, really, really, REALLY freaking hard." For this question, a good start would be to consider what sent Planet 2 onto a collision course with Planet 1 to begin with.

Comment: Well, I guess if we narrow down the possibilities to current technology, it wouldn't make any sense. I'll read that thread. Probably will end up building some kind of Handwavitor Device or something, heh.

Comment: It all depends on the scale. For example, if you have lots of time, you can alter the orbit of the approaching planet in tiny increments until it at the very least is no longer a direct threat. (In artificially creating a double planet system, though, you are going to have to content with tidal forces; try searching for Roche limit for a start.)

Comment: If you [edit] your question to indicate the level of technology, and the respective sizes of both planets, it'll probably be easier to judge whether this question is a duplicate of an existing one or give a good answer. As it stands, Rob Watts' comment is probably about as close to an answer as we can get, and as such, the question may very well end up being closed just because you are asking for too much. Consider [What topics can I ask about here?](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), specifically the point on specificity.

Comment: Tides on the planets would be... an issue (with or without the tether).

Comment: @MichaelT Yeah, I was thinking on that. It would be a mess... Agh! I wonder if Robert Forward cared about ANY of this when he wrote Rocheworld.

Comment: @A.CLouis Indeed he did. The planets are egg shaped (pulling planet A or B into an egg shape would likely have some catastrophic nature). Each is carefully balanced within the roche lobe. But again, note the shape of the planet. The closest you could ***possibly*** get is 2.4 planet radiuses apart. Though going to the hard math to get the 'what is the closest two earth mass planets could orbit a common barycenter?" would be one way to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be far easier to just move one of the planets a little so they don't collide if there's a large velocity difference.

If the planets are just barely going to collide, it seems like it might make sense to try to catch one. The problem is once you've caught it, the two planets will destroy each other from gravity. Unless your magical tech device can magically prevent gravity from working, you'll get something like this:
[image: Planets melting onto each other from gravity.]

The only way you're going to avoid this is if the planets are far enough apart that they don't tear each other apart. At this point, the best bet is just to get the new planet into orbit around the old planet.

I thought there was a question about *how* to move planets around, but I'm not finding it right now.

Comment: Yeah, maybe the best way to handle it is to somehow get Planet B in orbit around Planet A. They would end up in a Pluto-like setting. Assuming they don't collide with each other. Also, pretty awesome illustrations!

Comment: Try this: http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21605/could-you-create-a-travelling-planet/21636#21636

Comment: @A.CLouis Note that technically, Charon does not orbit Pluto, *nor* does Pluto orbit Charon! Instead, the barycenter of the Pluto-Charon system is *outside of either body*, with the two orbiting a common center of mass that is actually in between them. That makes the Pluto-Charon system unique (as far as I am aware) in our solar system. If you have two similarly sized planets capturing each other and surviving, that's the effect you will get. The barycenter is only inside either body if there is a large difference in mass between the two.

Comment: See also [Can a nonspherical planet exist and can it be habitable?](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/8772/29).

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 separate tasks: avoiding collision and forming double planet.

1. To avoid collision you need to give incoming planet lateral push. If collision is far ahead then this push can be relatively small - for 1 year and 30K km miss you need only 1 m/s. Though, of course it is hard to change planets speed even by 1 m/s since we are talking about trillions of trillions kgs. But you can put engines on asteroid, and make it "hang" to the side of the planet so that gravitational pull from asteroid would change planets trajectory.
2. To form double planet on other hand is much harder. Two passing bodies don't just start rotating around each other on it's own. They need to lose speed to do that. Otherwise, as they come closer, they would speed up just enough to reach escape velocity(because there is conservation of energy - binary planet has less potential energy than 2 separate planets). And we are talking about losing some km/s. So this task is 3 orders of magnitude harder than the first one.

So, if civilization thinks about creating double planet, then collision is not a threat, if it can barely escape a collision, then creation of double planet is out of question.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably need an artificial black hole as a stopgap measure to do the capturing but in theory you could get your two worlds orbiting a mutual centre of gravity like Pluto and Charon. I'm pretty sure that having done this the two worlds will be tidally locked to each other as they orbit that centre though so you're going to lose a lot of habitat on both worlds. If you actually have the technology to capture a world in this fashion you can probably produce a better outcome.

Comment: It'd be kinda neat to use that black hole AS the barycenter. I mean, gravity and tides would still have troubles, but...

Comment: @Pyrotrain That gives you a three-body system orbiting a star. And of course all the issues with having a black hole nearby. You don't need an actual celestial body at the location of the barycenter; just a common center of mass. As I discussed in (much) earlier comments, look at the Pluto/Charon system.

Comment: The planets won't automatically be tidally locked for millions, perhaps billions, of years. A civilization advanced enough to create spontaneous gravity wells likely would have no trouble tidally locking or unlocking either of the planets to or from the other.

Comment: @MichaelS Not sure that the rotational mechanics are that simple.